# Find the remainder of $9^2\cdot 13\cdot 21^2$ when divided by $4$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

> Find the remainder of $9^2\cdot 13\cdot 21^2$ when divided by $4$

How should I approach this type of questions?

Without calculator of course

I did this:

$9^2\cdot 13\cdot 21^2=81\cdot 13\cdot 441=81\cdot 5733=464,373=33\bmod 4=1 \bmod 4$

Comment: See the  properties of congruence : http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Congruence.html

Comment: $$(4a+1)^2(4b+1)(4c+1)^2=4k+1$$ for some $k\in\mathbb{N}.$

Comment: @Nilan see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**: What is $9\bmod 4$? What is $13\bmod 4$?

How would you proceed from here?

---

Also, you wrote that $464\,373=1\bmod 4$. Always keep in mind that the "$=$" sign means that two things are exactly the same, in every way. In stead one should write

- $\overline{464\,373}=1\bmod 4$,
- $464\,373\bmod 4=1\bmod 4$,
- $\overline{464\,373}=\overline 1$ (when it is understood that we are working in $\mathbb Z/4\mathbb Z$)

or

- $464\,373\equiv 1\bmod 4$.

Comment: Can I do this: $9\mod 4=1$ and $13 \mod 4=1$ so the only thing that I have to check is $21^2\mod 4$?

Comment: You certainly **can** do this. You also **can** do what you did in the first place. However, with these kind of exercises you are supposed to learn how to work quickly $\bmod 4$. So is there any way you can know what $21^2\bmod 4$ is, without calculating $21^2$?

Answer (score 2):

$9^2*13*21^2$ is not a multiple of 4 or two.

Hence it cannot be 0 or 2 (mod 4)

$9^2*13*21^2$ can be written as

$9^2*21^2*(3^2+2^2) =$

$(9*21*3)^2 + (9*21*2)^2$

A sum of squares cannot give 3 (mod 4)

Hence it is 1 (mod 4)

Answer (score 1):

$(9^2\cdot13\cdot21^2)\bmod4=$

$((9\bmod4)^2\cdot(13\bmod4)\cdot(21\bmod4)^2)\bmod4=$

$(1^2\cdot1\cdot1^2)\bmod4=$

$1\bmod4$